# How to submit a form using jquery dialog button?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hello guys just want to ask about how can i process a form submission using the jquery dialog button. In my code I have a button that when you click. It will pop up a form in a dialog box. Below is the jquery buttons for OK and CANCEL. My problem is I can't submit my form the only option that I have is to create a submit button inside my form. But i want to use the jquery button instead. Im using CodeIgniter I hope you can help me.

My view (showAllSuppliers.php)

```
 /* FOR ADD PAGE */    
    $(".hero-unit input[name=add_supplier]").on('click',function(){
        $('#popup').load("<?php echo site_url("supplier_controller/addNewSupplier/"); ?>").dialog({
            title: "Add New Supplier",
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 800,
            modal:true,
            position: "center",
            buttons: {
                OK: function(){
                     $("#addSupplier").submit(); //HOW CAN I SUBMIT MY FORM USING THIS?
                },
                CANCEL: function() {
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

my form (addNewSupplier.php)

```
<?php
$attr = array('id'=>'addSupplier');
echo form_open('supplier_controller/insertNewSupplier');  
..
.. 
..
... MY TEXTBOX FIELDS HERE
..
..
//echo "<input type='submit' value='ADD' />"; ANOTHER OPTION FOR SUBMISSION
echo form_close();
?>
```

my controller function(supplier_controller.php)

```
 public function insertNewSupplier(){

        $this->supplier_model->insertNewSupplierDetail();
        redirect('supplier_controller/index','refresh');

 }
```

Comment: $('#formId').submit();

Comment: i tried that. Here's what i did `OK: function(){
                     $("#addSupplier").submit(); //HOW CAN I SUBMIT MY FORM USING THIS?
                },`

Comment: it doesn't not submit my form also.

Comment: is this a jquery ui dialog?

Comment: yes. I included a button for OK and CANCEL

Comment: make sure you only have one element with an id of addSupplier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by just changing this line and your usual js:

```
$attr = array('id'=>'addSupplier');
echo form_open('supplier_controller/insertNewSupplier', $attr);
```

If still does not submits the form then try to submit by ajax call.

```
$(".hero-unit input[name=add_supplier]").on('click',function(){
    $('#popup').load("<?php echo site_url("supplier_controller/addNewSupplier/"); ?>").dialog({
        title: "Add New Supplier",
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 800,
        modal:true,
        position: "center",
        buttons: {
            OK: function(){
                 $.ajax({
                    url     : '<?=base_url()?>supplier_controller/insertNewSupplier',
                    type    : 'POST',
                    data    : $("#addSupplier").serializeArray(),
                    success : function(resp){
                        alert("Submitted !!!");
                        $(this).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    error   : function(resp){
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(resp));
                    }
                 });
            },
            CANCEL: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i did that. After i fill up the fields and click the OK button there's an alert pop up but the form does not go to my controller.

Comment: what does it alerted?

Comment: change this line : `data    : $("#addSupplier").serializeArray(),` to `data    : {'data' : $("#addSupplier").serializeArray()},` and this `alert("Submitted !!!");` to `alert("Submitted !!!"+resp);`. On your controller write `print_r($_POST);die;` in the first line. Let me know the alert it gave.

Comment: when i clicked the OK button a pop up appeared displaying the word Submitted and a sets of array.

Comment: Yeah right. Now you just need to pass that array in your model and write the code for the insert. That's it. Your form is submitted ! :D

Comment: one more question how can i pass the array in my model?

Comment: as of now my controller contains the print_r($_POST);

Comment: How can i access or pass it in my model?

Comment: Should i directly call it like $this->input->post('sample_name'); ?

Comment: write : `$this->model_name->function_name($this->input->post('data'))`. In your model declare a function like `function function_name($form_array){//your code here}`

Comment: what does $this->input->post('data') means? is it my textfield name? so if i have many text field i need to call my model according to the number of the textboxes.

Comment: or should i place $this->input->post('data') in an array and pass it to my model?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33967/discussion-between-niloy-saha-and-user2585508)

Answer (score 0):

You need ajax call

```
$('#submit').click(function (){
        var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
        $.ajax({
            url : '/supplier_controller/insertNewSupplier,
            type : 'post',
                    data : first_name,
            success : function(){
                        //do something;
                        console.log(first_name);
                    }           
                })
                    return false;
            });
```

That's gonna work if you ad id to submit button and to your input. But you can also call them via html tags. It's just an idea or example for you.

Comment: The previous example works only for submit button. Is there a way how can i get the button id of the jquery ui dialog button?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use classic form submission instead of ajax call, write these code lines for the ***buttons*** parameter:

```
buttons: {
            OK: function(){
                 $(this).dialog().find('form').submit();
            },
            CANCEL: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
```